# Formatting Time Variables when computing basic statistics

Tags: sas

It seems like when I perform a proc means or proc report on my data that has time variables in this format: HH:MM:SS it comes out as a number. I'm not sure how I can format it back to HH:MM:SS when I'm calculating the mean,median, mode, etc

Comment: There is another question which which sounds the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498362/format-the-summarised-variables-from-proc-summary). Does that provide what you need? If not, then please edit your question to provide an example.

Comment: [Here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001263753.htm) is a list of formats by category. You should be able to find what you're looking for.